# How can I use sed to insert some text after a multiline match?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file `sample.txt` like this:

```
lots of text
lots of text


#nvram = [
#   these
#   could
#   be,
#   anything
#]

lots of text
lots of text
```

and I want to add some text "foobar" to get this:

```
lots of text
lots of text


#nvram = [
#   these
#   could
#   be,
#   anything
#]
foobar

lots of text
lots of text
```

I have looked at some related threads and tried a bunch of stuff but have not been able to join the information together in the correct way.

multiline matching:
[How can I use sed or ex to replace a block (multi-line code) with new block of text (code)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303644/how-can-i-use-sed-or-ex-to-replace-a-block-multi-line-code-with-new-block-of-t)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234001/replace-multiple-lines-using-sed
[How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

appending: 
[How to add a new line after the "test message1" using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/how-to-add-a-new-line-after-the-test-message1-using-sed)

I've been trying stuff like this:

```
sed  '/^#nvram = \[$/{
    N
    ^.*$
}/abc123/' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/ {N; s/\<^#nvram = \[$\>\n<^.*$\>/abc123/g}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/ {N; s/\<#nvram = \[\>\n\<.*\>/abc123/g}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/ {N; s/#nvram = \[\n.*/abc123/g}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/ {N; /#nvram = \[\n.*/abc123/a}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/ {N; /#nvram = \[(\n.*){1,}/abc123/a}' sample.txt


sed '/^#nvram = \[$/!b;n;cABC' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/N;cABC' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/N/#\]/a;cABC' sample.txt


sed '/^#nvram = \[$/,/#\]/{/^#nvram = \[$/n;/#\]/!{s/./abc/g}}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/,/#\]/{/^#nvram = \[$/n;/#\]/!{/abc/a}}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/,/#\]/{/^#nvram = \[$/n;/#\]/!/a abc}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/,/#\]/{/^#nvram = \[$/n;/#\]/;/a abc}' sample.txt

sed '/^#nvram = \[$/,/#\]/{/^#nvram = \[$/n;/#\]/a abc}' sample.txt
```

But so far I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a loop?

```
sed '/^#nvram = \[/{
:a                          
N                                                  
/\n#\]/!ba                                                                  
a\
foobar
}
' sample.txt
```

Explanation:

```
:a              # begin loop
N               # append next line to pattern space
/\n#\]/!ba      # if we haven't matched the end marker yet, branch back to a
a\              # append after loop exits
foobar
```

At least in GNU sed, this can be written as a one-liner

```
sed -e '/^#nvram = \[/{:a; N; /\n#\]/!ba; a\foobar' -e '}' sample.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the slow response, I had some distractions. All of the answers worked for me but I'm crediting you because you were first.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `-z`:

```
$ sed -z 's/#nvram = \[.*\]/&\nfoobar\n/' file
lots of text
lots of text


#nvram = [
#   these
#   could
#   be,
#   anything
#]
foobar

lots of text
lots of text
```

You may need to tweak the regexp depending what you really mean by "anything" (e.g. can it contain a `]`) and whether or not you have other similar blocks in your file.

This would be more robust, for example, if `anything` doesn't include `]`s and you have other similar blocks in your input:

```
sed -z 's/#nvram = \[[^]]*\]/&\nfoobar\n/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll pick one of the approaches you took and show you how to make it work, so that it resonates and also stays with you:

```
$ sed -e '
   /^#nvram = \[$/,/^#]$/!b
   /^#]$/a\
Foobar
' sample.txt
```

I personally don't like the above nd do somewhat differently:

```
$ sed -e '
   /^#nvram = \[$/,/^#]$/!b
   /^#]$/G
   s/\n/&Foobar/
' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's also a simple sed:

```
sed '/#nvram = \[/,/#]/ s/#]/#]\nfoobar/' file
```

It finds a line in which the `#nvram = [` has occurred and then all the lines after that and until the first occurence of an `#]` is addressed, then you substitute the `#]\nfoobar` for `#]`.

Comment: In one line, cool! Thanks!